# Change the IDs dynamically

Tags: javascript

I've got some inputs as below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-1" name="e_id[]" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-2" name="e_id[]" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-3" name="e_id[]" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-4" name="e_id[]" />
```

I also have buttons for each input which removes that input.

But, when I remove for example the `"selected_id-2"` input, I would like to update the id's of the next inputs. So the `"selected_id-3"` would become `"selected_id-2"`, and the `"selected_id-4"` - `"selected_id-3"`.

How could I update those id's?
Pure JavaScript needed, no frameworks.

Comment: No jQuery? It is also pure JavaScript. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Jquery is Javascript

Comment: @TWCrap - Yeah dude Thats what I said!

Comment: ow, sorry, my bad. readed wrong.

Comment: You really are getting everyone to code your app for you.

Comment: @epascarello, I'm just looking for the ways it could be achieved. And I found one more simplified than that one I've coded.

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR you should SHOW the way you coded so it does not look like you are always asking for someone to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your markup, there's probably a better way to get to all of your inputs, for instance, finding all within a given container, but lacking such information, you could still do something like:

```
function updateIds() {

   var count = 0;

   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i = 0; l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
      if(inputs[i].name == 'e_id[]') {

         inputs[i].id = 'selected_id-' + (++count);

      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this ?

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    els[i].id = 'selected_id-'+i;
}
```

If you want something more precise, even without jQuery (but with a [not too old browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)), you can do this :

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="e_id[]"]');
```

Comment: this would change all the ids

Comment: It partially looks like what I want.

Comment: This will work but it is very fragile... If there are any other inputs of any type then this function will make a mess of the other elements.

Comment: @scunliffe did you look at my proposition to use querySelectorAll ? This must be refined to the need of OP but that's not fragile at all.

Comment: @dystroy ah yes, nice addition! When I made the comment that part wasn't there yet. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the `<input>` elements into an array. You iterate through that array and then when you've reached the number you want, you replace `'select_id-'+(i)` with `'select_id-'+(i-1)`.

Here's how to get an array of all `<input>` elements:

```
var myControls = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

And then you go through a for (concept code):

```
for (var i = 1; i < [length of myControls]; i++) { 
    if (this_id's_number < i) {
        continue;
    } else if (this_id's_number == i) {
        remove this input
    } else {
        current_number = getCurrentNumberFromID();

        current input's id = current_number -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method in JavaScript called [`setAttribute()`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_setattribute.asp).

#### JavaScript Way:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("selected_id-2"); 
elem.setAttribute("id", "selected_id-3");
elem.id = "selected_id-3";
```

#### jQuery Way:

```
$("#selected_id-2").attr("id", "selected_id-3");
```

Comment: You don't need setAttribute to set the id. By the way I hadn't **yet** downvoted.

Comment: To be clearer : `document.getElementById("selected_id-2").id="newid";` perfectly works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some DOM gymnatstic like

```
document.getElementById("elementId").id.value="newId"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#selected_id-" + number_to_change).attr('id',"selected_id-"+(number_to_change-1));
```